# Is [Synthetic] fuel for burnination?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I've come across the [synthetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synthetic) tag - it is used for a variety of concepts and after 7 years is still without a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synthetic/info).

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   No, it is used for a wide range of concepts, from "constructs generated by compilers that do not have corresponding representions in source code" to "kotlin synthetic imports" to "generating test data".
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   Hard to tell as it is so vague. Questions about compiler-generated constructs are certainly on-topic, as are questions about generation of test data.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   No. Without further context provided by the question, it is impossible to tell what the question is about.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   No. Generating test data is fundamentally different from generated methods and classes - the only thing the questions have in common is that "something" is "generated".

---

There are currently 47 questions with this tag.

---

Other tags that might be better suited for some of the questions:

There is a more specific [java-synthetic-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-synthetic-methods) for synthetic methods in java, but no such tag for synthetic fields or classes.

There is [data-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-generation), which might be more suitable for questions that ask about generating test data.

There is [compiler-generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-generated), but it may be inappropriate for the java topics, because these constructs are not *necessarily* generated by a compiler.

Comment: Synthetic classes are a concept in Java. The first questions on this tag are about that, and a significant portion of the others. It probably deserves an excerpt and some cleanup, but I think the tag is on-topic and salvageable.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I agree that most of the questions are on-topic, but they have little in common (I've noticed the tag when writing an answer to one of them). There is the related tag [tag:java-synthetic-methods], which might be an appropriate retagging-target for some of the questions.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think that comment deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It identifies a Java topic, but it identifies a lot of other topics too.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this request. The tag adds nothing of value to the questions - it's not like people can use it to locate questions they're interested in, and this tag isn't even identifying a topic. You can't be an expert in "synthetic".

These questions can easily do without the tag, or be re-tagged with something more specific. We can, for example, create a [java-synthetic-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-synthetic-classes) tag for questions on that topic.

Also worth noting: this is eligible for abbreviated burnination since it has less than 50 questions if a 20k user buys in to the request.